# User Managment Loop is stuck

Tags: python-3.x

When I call Login, the link never opens.

I receive no error messages.

My user account information is stored in a txt file which is called `accounts`.

I have tried switching tabbing and changing the webbrowser command but nothing works.

When I login again it just asks me if I want to login register or log out like the beginning does.

```
def Login():
    loggedin = 0
    url = 'https://www.google.com'

    us = input("To login enter Username: ")
    pa = input("To login enter Password: ")
    with open('accounts.txt', 'r') as myFile:

        for x in myFile.readlines():
            userdata = x.split(",")
            if userdata[0] == us and userdata[1] == pa:
                print("You have been Logged in") and loggedin = 1
            else
                print("Wrong Login")

            if loggedin == 1:
                webbrowser.open(url)
```

This is the first part.

```
while not exit:

    print('1. Make an account')
    print('2. Login')
    print('3. Logout')
    print('4. Exit')

    s = input('Make a selection: ')

    if s == '1':
        functions.register()

    elif s == '2':
        functions.Login()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! It will help everyone understand your problem if you can show the error message you receive and demonstrate some attempts you made to solve the problem.

Comment: I added more detail thanks for the tip